# MS SQL 2005 - Replace Null values with linear interpolation

Tags: sql-server

I have a set of data below with date and value in MS SQL 2005. The values for some dates are NULL. What is the best way to fill the Null values with linear interpolation?

```
Date,ShortName,LongName,Value
12/31/2012,ABC,Test1,-4.0
12/31/2012,XYZ,Test2,-8.1
1/2/2013,ABC,Test1,NULL
1/2/2013,XYZ,Test2,NULL
1/3/2013,ABC,Test1,NULL
1/3/2013,XYZ,Test2,NULL
1/4/2013,ABC,Test1,-9.6
1/4/2013,XYZ,Test2,-13.0
1/7/2013,ABC,Test1,NULL
1/7/2013,XYZ,Test2,NULL
1/8/2013,ABC,Test1,NULL
1/8/2013,XYZ,Test2,NULL
1/9/2013,ABC,Test1,NULL
1/9/2013,XYZ,Test2,NULL
1/10/2013,ABC,Test1,NULL
1/10/2013,XYZ,Test2,NULL
1/11/2013,ABC,Test1,-7.1
1/11/2013,XYZ,Test2,-12.7
```

Comment: Do you have a particular algorithm you'd like to use?

Comment: So just interpolate based on `Date` and `Value`?  If you expect `ShortName` and `LongName` to participate then a little more information might help.

Comment: Linear interpolation *is* an algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

Comment: Yes. I can do this in excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach that seems to be giving decent results for me:

```
select *
from tests
where value is not null
union all
select t.Date
  , t.ShortName
  , t.LongName
  , Value = p.Value + (n.Value - p.Value)
    * (cast(datediff(dd, p.Date, t.Date) as decimal(16,1)))
    / (cast(datediff(dd, p.Date, n.Date) as decimal(16,1)))
from tests t
  cross apply
  (
    select top 1 p.date, p.value
    from tests p
    where p.Value is not null
      and t.shortname = p.shortname
      and t.date > p.date
    order by p.date desc
  ) p
  cross apply
  (
    select top 1 n.date, n.value
    from tests n
    where n.Value is not null
      and t.shortname = n.shortname
      and t.date < n.date
    order by n.date
  ) n
where t.Value is null
order by ShortName, Date
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eaaa6/12).

Another [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eaaa6/13) with more debug information, i.e. the x, x0, y, etc values I used.

Though your data doesn't have weekends, I assumed the line would include weekend days, too. If not I'm sure the query can be tweaked.

Comment: Hi Ian,I think I should describe it better. This is what I did in Excel: Sort by shortname and date so that values for ABC is in the range of A2:D10, filling cell D3 with  D2+($D$5-$D$2)/3, cell D4 with D3+($D$5-$D$2)/3... This way the graph between 12/31/2012 an 1/4/2013 is a line. Is it possible to do the same with SQL

Comment: To make the problem simple, I can use the data for ABC only.

Comment: I added Row_number() over (order by shortname, date) and replaced the datediff by difference of row numbers and it gives me the same results as Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear if you only want to interpolate within each ShortName or over the entire date range. Here is the simpler date range, but reply back if you want to partition by ShortName as well.

```
declare @Table table ([Date] datetime, ShortName varchar(100), LongName varchar(100), Value decimal(10,2));
insert into @Table
    select '12/31/2012','ABC','Test1','-4.0' union all
    select '12/31/2012','XYZ','Test2','-8.1' union all
    select '1/2/2013','ABC','Test1',NULL union all
    select '1/2/2013','XYZ','Test2',NULL union all
    select '1/3/2013','ABC','Test1',NULL union all
    select '1/3/2013','XYZ','Test2',NULL union all
    select '1/4/2013','ABC','Test1','-9.6' union all
    select '1/4/2013','XYZ','Test2','-13.0' union all
    select '1/7/2013','ABC','Test1',NULL union all
    select '1/7/2013','XYZ','Test2',NULL union all
    select '1/8/2013','ABC','Test1',NULL union all
    select '1/8/2013','XYZ','Test2',NULL union all
    select '1/9/2013','ABC','Test1',NULL union all
    select '1/9/2013','XYZ','Test2',NULL union all
    select '1/10/2013','ABC','Test1',NULL union all
    select '1/10/2013','XYZ','Test2',NULL union all
    select '1/11/2013','ABC','Test1','-7.1' union all
    select '1/11/2013','XYZ','Test2','-12.7'


;with stage as
(
    select  *, [r] = row_number() over (order by [Date])
    from    @Table
)
select  l.[Date], 
        [OldValue] = l.value,
        [NewValue] = isnull(l.Value, f.Value + (t.Value - f.Value) * (l.[r] - f.[r]) / (t.[r] - f.[r]))
from    stage l
outer 
apply   (   select  top 1 [Date], Value, [r]
            from    stage x
            where   x.[Date] < l.[Date] and
                    x.Value is not null
            order 
            by      [Date] desc
        ) f
outer 
apply   (   select  top 1 [Date], Value, [r]
            from    stage x
            where   x.[Date] > l.[Date] and
                    x.Value is not null
            order 
            by      [Date] asc
        ) t
order
by      [date] asc;
```

Comment: Nathan, I need to interpoate by datem short name, and long name, Ian's code is close to what I am looking for. I have done this in Excel but would like to learn how to do it with SQL. Thanks for trying to help.